# why does illustrator change layer names when export to svg

Tags: svg, adobe-illustrator

I've just started working with Adobe Illustrator and I stuck with a problem of exporting.
The names of my layers are renamed after exporting:
In Illustrator I have:

[image]

Export:

[image]

And file what I received:

[image]

So, how to manage that my output svg file will contain layer names which I added to Illustrator?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Answer is simple. I use combination the letters and numbers. In this case everything works fine.
Like:
1 = x1 etc.

Answer (score 0):

If Illustrator would try to use your layer names as node IDs those wouldn't be unique and therefore not compliant with HTML standards.

It's not a straight-forward answer, but I usually solve this by grouping nodes to few groups in Illustrator, setting relevant names to those groups and then cleaning exported SVG manually in text editor.

Comment: see my answer. I just use the combination of letters and numbers.

Comment: Glad, you figured it out :)